# Add a full width image above a Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to insert an image above a navbar, but I it is not working for me.  Here is my html:

```
  <div class="wrapper" />
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active">
            <a class="brand" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and my css:

```
.wrapper {
  background-image: url(../assets/bridge.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

Anytime I add a div or any content, it is pushed to the top of the page.  I can add padding, but when I start to resize the screen it breaks and leaves a gap in the image and the navbar.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/LunMH/

Comment: Give a proper answer so I can accept it.  I still cant find what the difference is though.  What did you do?

Comment: Ok i have written with proper explanation.. Check that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div />` means `<div>` in HTML 5 and not `<div></div>` as it does in XHTML.  `Div`'s are not valid self closing tags.

[Ref](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/syntax.html#syntax-start-tag)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7D389/)

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active">
            <a class="brand" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `/>` at the end of `.wrapper`, because it is not allowed (depending on your doctype). Remove it and give it `</div>` like the other divs, I think it's going to work.